# What am I doing wrong that when I change the format of datetime column, it automatically changes to a different format midway through?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, datetime

This is an example of my actual dataframe

[image]

I am trying to sort it in ascending order, date and time wise, and for that I am trying to change it to datetime object first. The format I want is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. It should be a simple task but somehow the format changes itself midway.

This is the output generated upon using `to_datetime`

[image]

Comment: in your input data, the day comes first. However, `pd.to_datetime` by default assumes that the month comes first. So you need to set keyword `dayfirst=True` when converting to datetime. Ex: `df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], dayfirst=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define the datetime format:

```
pd.to_datetime(MPPT['DT'], format=%d-%b-%Y %H:%M)
```

then there is no doubt how to interpret your datetime string. This is the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for all datetime formats.